# Sharepoint2010 Site is not opening in Mobile

Tags: anonymous-authentication, mobile

I am having site in Sharepoint 2010. It is working fine in all browsers.

But, when I open it in Mobile it shows me

> 401 Unauthorized access

I have **Anonymous Access** checked on this site from central admin.

I have also added **Browsercaps**  tag in `web.config` file

May I know other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to disable to MobileRedirect feature at the SPWeb level and see if that helps. A detailed explanation on disabling MobileRedirect can be found at the following url

http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/11/02/mobile-site-redirect-for-sharepoint-2010-public-site/